# Exit /dev/tty after error message

Tags: bash, shell-script, python, tty

I run this bash function when a button is pressed, it calls my mobile, however when the call ends or I reject the call, it hangs in /dev/tty and does not return to the main program

call.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

printf %s\\n 'call sip:in06khattab@ekiga.net' | cat - /dev/tty |twinkle -c
```

Here is the main program:

```
while(1):
if lcd.buttonPressed(lcd.SELECT):
   os.system("./call.sh")
```

When phone is offline or call is rejected, it hangs and does not return back to the python program:
[image]

I would then have to press CTRL + C and CTRL + Z to exit which closes the python program too.

[image]

Is it possible to return back to the main program after a 408 Request timeout error or a 468 Busy Here message?

[image]

EDIT:
The answer was `mkfifo /tmp/pipe; exec 3<>/tmp/pipe; (trap '' TTIN TTOU; twinkle -c) <&3 & printf '\ncall sip:'in06khattab@ekiga.net >&3` thanks to @mikeserv

Comment: You probably want to try CTRL-D at the start of a line. Still, I told you it was a hack.

Comment: How would that work if there needs to be a check if a 408 request timeout error occurred or a 468 Busy Here message. Also CTRL +D gives the same thing as CTRL +C

Comment: It *could* be more of a hack, though - you could insert a `head` or something between the `cat` and `twinkle` and add `/proc/self/stat` to the list of `cat`'s files like `cat /proc/self/stat - /dev/tty` - that would write a bunch of information about the `cat` process that you could capture and use to shut it down later - the first few bytes are the pid.

Comment: It's your python program, man. You need to ignore the signal.

Comment: Tried the /proc/self/stat and this is what I got http://prntscr.com/62r93w

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but what do you mean by  "You need to ignore the signal"?

Comment: Well, if you want friendlier output use `/proc/self/status`. Anyway, you would probably want to filter that so it doesn't get printed at your `twinkle` program - but you're just throwing bad time after good that way.

Comment: I mean the signal sent when `cat` dies. You have to handle it - it's what kill's your python script.

Comment: Well to kill twinkle I usually do this: sudo pkill -9 twinkle. I'll post a screenshot of the output of status

Comment: You pull no punches, huh? haha. You can't handle that signal.

Comment: Lol, here is the output of satus: http://imgur.com/a/dc0Ta

Comment: Well, if you recall, I suggested yesterday you might try it with a `luit` wrapper, too, right? If you did that, you could use the `-olog /file/name` and/or `-argv0` switches to name and monitor the process more closely. Do `man luit` and have a look.

Comment: I tried doing this but I had to press CTRL +C to get it to work: http://prntscr.com/62rmzk

Comment: Also tried luit, but it didnt work: http://prntscr.com/62rnwz

Comment: Actually, yeah, that's one way to go - does `twinkle` accept an `exit` command? If so, you can drop `/dev/tty` and open a named pipe instead - you'd then be able to print anything you like at the pipe - and you could probably do without `cat` altogether. Though `cat` might help to make the buffering a little better.

Comment: Yeah - for `luit` may need to do something like `printf ... | cat ... | { exec 3<&0 </dev/tty; luit -olog ./path/to/some/file -- sh -c 'cat <&3 | twinkle -c'; }` ... so the `luit` process can read a terminal on stdin and you can still feed it your input. I usually do instead though `</dev/ptmx luit ...` but that might or might not work depending on the permissions set on that device file. Anyway, I told you, it's a hack. A named pipe could be better: `mkfifo /tmp/pipe; exec 3<>/tmp/pipe; (trap '' TTIN TTOU; twinkle -c) <&3 & printf 'call sip:'... >&3`

Comment: ptmx didnt work due to permissions: http://prntscr.com/62s30d

Comment: You can `chown` it or `mount -o remount,ptxmode=...` and so forth, it but @roiama  is right - if you have to go through all of this work for your sip dialer then you either want a new dialer or you want to figure out why. You're working too hard for this man - why doesn't it work in the default way? If you want to do this lowlevel stuff then you probably don't want to do it with a native GUI app anyway - the two kinds program structure don't often come together easily

Comment: Your last idea was very nice. I tried it, but the output of twinkle seems to cut the input in half. I have tried to put a sleep but it does not seem to work: http://prntscr.com/62s53r

Comment: I am working on a raspberry pi which will be headless. I have tried other programs, but a lot of them crash on the pi and this is the only one I found that has a CLI that I can call headless.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by *cut in half* - do you mean only half of the characters you type in get through to `twinkle`? That can happen when you have two readers on the same terminal - are you still `cat`ting the terminal by any chance?

Comment: no, this is direct to the terminal, no cat is used here. Look at the third line from the bottom "call sip: i" This command has been cut in half and the rest of the command is on the bottom line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20957/discussion-between-mikeserv-and-hamoudy).

Answer (score 1):

If you want twinkle to place a call when you press your button, I would suggest that you get your key-monitoring program to use twinkle's command line to do that directly:

twinkle -c --immediate --call sip:in06khattab@ekiga.net

It would be far easier that all this fiddling around with ttys, etc.

Or have I misunderstood your intent?

Comment: it is just a gpio button which I have programmed to do other functions too such as send an email.